# unsetting regular key on emacs

Tags: emacs, key-bindings

This is a little embarrassing, but recently I happen to bind regular keys on the fly using `global-set-key` every week or two.
e.g.
I bound the `q` key to `quoted-insert` and `toggle-read-only` today (not on purpose)
I tried `global-unset-key`, but now pressing the `q` key gives me `q is undefined` message (and writes nothing).
Since it isn't the first time this happens to me recently and since I hate losing all the buffers opened in my emacs every time it happens to me, I'm looking for a way to unset a char key without losing the ability to write this char *OR* to rebind the char to itself (`global-set-key` not allowing it). Trying to bind to `insert-char 71` failed as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(global-set-key (kbd "q") #'self-insert-command)
```

This is the default binding for all alphanumeric keys (which of course can be overridden in some major or minor mode).

There isn't a way to reset a key to its default that I'm aware of.  If you want to play around with key bindings in a reversible way, probably the best thing to do is make your own minor mode and only bind keys to it (see http://shallowsky.com/blog/linux/editors/emacs-global-key-bindings.html).  Then you can easily toggle the mode off, or undefine a key in its map, to get the global binding.

Finally, I use `save-visited-files` (in melpa) to remember (most of) my buffers.  There are more complete solutions like `desktop` to save and restore state as well.

Comment: excellent. never knew about the `self-insert-command`. Thanks.